# Map subfolder to subdomain in Apache

Tags: domain-name-system, domain

I am trying to map `ugc.domain.com` to `domain.com/ugc` on my website, basically taking the subfolder and putting it in the front (I already did the DNS mapping on Digital Ocean for `ugc.domain.com`).

I tried the following RewriteRule:

```
RewriteRule ^/ugc/?$ http://ugc.domain.com/ [R=301,L]
```

Reloaded Apache, but navigating to `ugc.domain.com` did not go to my `domain.com/UGC` page.

So basically what I want to do is, when I go to `ugc.domain.com`, in the background, I am actually going to `domain.com/ugc`, even though in the URL, it says `ugc.domain.com`. I think it looks prettier and cleaner this way.

Answer (score 1):

This rule does the opposite what you want. This one sends a `301 Moved Permanently` response to the client when the user visits `http://domain.com/ugc/` page, sending the client to `http://ugc.domain.com`.

What you are actually looking is to define a new virtualhost for `ugc.domain.com`, and then set that virtual host's directory location to the directory where `domain.com/UGC` page is.

Comment: Hi Tero. Could you show me with code what you mean? I'm still not really understanding what I did wrong.

Comment: http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.2/vhosts/examples.html -page shows examples how virtualhosts are defined in Apache. Unfortunately I cannot give any more specific examples.